# How can i implement the rating control in xbox?

Tags: xaml, uwp, xbox

I have added the callisto rating control in my uwp appliication to allow the user to provide the rating on the products and it works properly.But how can i implement this in xbox side as there is no mouse control to select the rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse mode is on by default for all applications, which means that all applications that have not opted out will receive a mouse pointer, so you do not need to care about it. You could do the same behavior by using XBOX controller. See [How to disable mouse mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/how-to-disable-mouse-mode) for more details.